# Messed up. How to reinstall/restore fonts on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to install some fonts on Ubuntu and instead messed up rendering fonts on ubuntu altogether.

Currently, all fonts in all apps (except for Chrome which I'm typing in now) render characters as 'empty squares', including the system itself such as terminal, etc.

Of course this is completely unusable. 
Last thing I remembered trying was something like (to get newly installed fonts to work (from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1976037)

`sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/*`

Could this have caused the issue? 
Anyone got any clue what to try to get Ubuntu running normal again?

Comment: if its solely  graphical that is screwy  from tty  reinstall your graphical    `` sudo apt-get reinstall $graphical (for ex. gnome,kde,cinnamon,lxde) then re-login or reboot

Answer (score 0):

If you need to (terminal is totally unuseable)  chroot into your installed system (with networking ) and reinstall truetype*

```
 sudo apt-get install truetype\*
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I tty1 terminal works and displays fonts correctly. However doing the above shows `couldn't find any package by regex truetype*`. The fact that tty1 works: would that mean the problem is with the graphical skin instead? Total noob I'm afraid :/